# How to convert Map to List of User Object?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a HashMap with the following structure:

```
Map<Object, List<OtherObject>>
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
List<FinalObject>
```

being FinalObject:

```
public class FinalObject {
    private Object object;
    private List<OtherObject> otherObject;
}
```

Comment: Just iterate the entry set `.entrySet()` and collect the entries into a list. You can do that with a straightforward `for`-loop or a stream, if you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have a constructor like:

```
public FinalObject(Object obj, List<OtherObject> list) {
    this.object = obj;
    this.otherObject = list;
}
```

then you can do:

```
List<FinalObject> newList = map.entrySet()
                               .stream().map(e -> new FinalObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

A corresponding `forEach` approach would be:

```
List<FinalObject> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((k,v) -> finalList.add(new FinalObject(k, v)));
```

Comment: I like the use of the `forEach`. Very elegant